# displaying rows in blocked table pattern

Tags: php, mysql, sql

ok I have a database table named `item` which is laid out like (`user_id, Item_id, value`) each person is allowed up to 16 items in the table. I can display the 60 results in a 16 blocked vertical table. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to display an array in a 4X4 blocked column like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>result1</td>
      <td>result2</td>
      <td>result3</td>
      <td>result4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>result5</td>
      <td>result6</td>
      <td>result7</td>
      <td>result8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>result9</td>
      <td>result10</td>
      <td>result11</td>
      <td>result12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>result13</td>
      <td>result14</td>
      <td>result15</td>
      <td>result16</td>
  </tr>
</table
```

here is my array

```
 <?php

    require "connect.php";

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT item_id FROM items");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $column) {
            echo '<td>', $column, '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `modulo` operator against the current iteration of the result set to determine if you should create a new row or not. `if ($i % 4 === 0)`. You'll need to make your own `$i` variable to count which iteration you're on.

Comment: k ill google an example of that